# How variable behave in for loop have changed

Tags: julia

Consider this source code

```
println("Julia language version ",VERSION)
i=666
for i = 1:2
    println("i is $i")
end
println("global i is $i")

function main()
    j = 666
    for j = 1:2
        println("j is $j")
    end
    println("global j is $j")
end

main()
```

Consider the output of version 0.6

```
Julia language version 0.6.3
i is 1
i is 2
global i is 2
j is 1
j is 2
global j is 2
```

Compare to the output of version 1.0

```
Julia language version 1.0.0
i is 1
i is 2
global i is 666
j is 1
j is 2
global j is 666
```

I can't change the value of variable i and variable j using a for loop like I can before in version 0.6

I think C programmers will have the shock of their lives...

Comment: C programmers will be just fine. The for loop effectively now effectively does `for(int i = 1; i<=2; ++i)` rather than `for(i = 1; i<=2; ++i)`which is arguably the more robust way to do it in c as well, since the latter is just asking for bugs to happen, and any inheritance from an enclosing scope is best made explicit in c as well.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Julia 0.7 (which is basically == 1.0 with deprecations) you would see the necessary deprecation messages for the intended behaviour change:

```
┌ Warning: Deprecated syntax `implicit assignment to global variable `i``.
│ Use `global i` instead.
└ @ none:0
┌ Warning: Loop variable `i` overwrites a variable in an enclosing scope. In the future the variable will be local to the loop instead.
└ @ none:0
i is 1
i is 2
global i is 2
```

So to get what you want you could write:

```
function main()
    global j = 666
    for j = 1:2
        println("j is $j")
    end
    println("global j is $j")
end

main()
```

Your first example on the global level should theoretically be dealt with using `for outer i..` as described in https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/variables-and-scoping/#For-Loops-and-Comprehensions-1 but currently this is not handled in the REPL. See this issue: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/24293